# [solved]Resistors used in LM386 amplifier

Tags: resistors, lm386

I have found a [circuit to bass bump headphone amplifier](http://makezine.com/projects/make-37/bass-bump-headphone-amp/). In the parts list most of the resistors are 1/8 W, but I have only found 1/4W resistors. Will this effect the functioning of the amplifier? Should I increase the battery voltage now?

Answer (score 9):

The power rating only affects the ability of the resistor to dissipate power as heat. The 1/4W resistors will just be a little larger in physical size (so they can dissipate a higher power), and won't affect the electrical behaviour of this type of circuit.

When you get to very large power ratings then the resistors can change type from carbon/metal film to wirewound and they can have significantly different high frequency behaviour. But you don't have to worry about that in your situation.